# Retreiveing last line of the output from an external command

Tags: perl

I have stored the output of a script in $a variable, from this variable i want only the last line, What should i use to get the last line from this variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get last few lines of file stored in variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671065/get-last-few-lines-of-file-stored-in-variable)

Comment: Actually i m executing the tcl script using perl and i m getting many lines of output, But i want only the last line. Is there any another method?

Comment: @toolic's question is still relevant. At some point you are storing the results of the call to the tcl script in `$a`.  Instead of doing that, store it in `@lines`, and then it's a trivial matter to get the last line: `$lines[-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

The following avoids collecting all the output in the first place:

```
open(my $pipe, '|-', @cmd);
my $last_line;
$last_line = $_ while <$pipe>;
close($pipe);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
my ($last) = $str =~  /.+\R(.+)$/;
```

Comment: help me to understand the benefit of the `.+\R` sequence here?  Since we're not using `/s`, the `.` will not match newlines.  Are there sequences in the `\R` character class (line breaks) that do not include the newline character?  Or in other words, what edge case would be correctly found by this, but not by simply `/(.+)$/` ?

Comment: @PaulL: Yes, you're right, `/(.+)$/` is enough. I've given the answer in a hurry.